# How to get timestamp with timezone in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, typeorm, apollo-server

I have a table with a date field of type timestamp with time zone, the field in the typeorm model is of type date. I use a nodejs express server.

When I get the datetime it returns the value with one hour less.

How can I solve it?

Value in the database:

2022-11-23 00:08:00+01

Value returned by the server:

2022-11-22T23:08:00.000Z

Comment: Time and dates are hard.

Answer (score 0):

The times are the same, your database is storing as Time Zone +1 and the value is returned in UTC/ZULU/GMT time, Time Zone 0. If you need to retain the Time Zone offset you will probably need to handle that in the resolver or perhaps in a custom Scalar.

I've seen this handled on the client as well to change the time to the wanted Time Zone.